# YQL - Yahoo Geo API

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

The following query using the Yahoo API started to return a result of 'null' since yesterday. (in fact all my queries against the geo.placefinder) return result: null.

Is anyone aware of an update / work that yahoo is doing? I have tried using their developer console but that returns null result as well. This query is a crucial part of my application that now is dysfunctional.

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%22sfo%22&format=json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem, as I understand the placefinder was meant to be shutdown on Nov 17, 2012 and we were meant to use the paid service Boss Geo.

see:

https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/introducing-boss-geo-next-chapter-boss-53654.html#more-id2

YQL tables for development
If you are looking to continue experimenting with the standalone PlaceFinder and PlaceMaker services, we are excited to continue supporting you through our YQL tables. These tables will be limited to 2,000 queries per day and are meant for non-commercial usage. We intend to shut down the current free versions of PlaceFinder and PlaceMaker on November 17, 2012.

Workaround:

For a direct replace of the current url you can use a combination or YQL and gws2.maps.yahoo.com. For example, to get the location of the random co-ordinates below the url will be the following:

```
var url = https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fgws2.maps.yahoo.com%2Ffindlocation%3Fpf%3D1%26locale%3Den_US%26offset%3D15%26flags%3D%26gflags%3DR%26q%3D52.01%2C4.82%27&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys
```

to execute it with ajax it would be something like the following:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: getWeatherForLocation,
    error: appErrorHandler
});
```

Comment: Interesting - but the above query worked until yesterday (and I've been using it since last year), how is that possible? :(

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of a replacement solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is the same as the post at [Yahoo YQL query with gFlags returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904938/yahoo-yql-query-with-gflags-returns-nothing?noredirect=1#comment57551838_34904938)

Several solutions to this are posted on that thread.

Comment: None of those solutions help, the API returns 503.

Comment: a 503 is a different issue and not related. The yahoo API returns a 503 sometimes when calls to it are at capacity. If you are using the public api (i.e. not using a app id in your call) then you are at the mercy of Yahoo's daily limits.

Comment: I just tested your YQL url changing placefinder to places(1) and it works. It does not return a 503.

Comment: can you post the actual query?

Comment: [https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22sfo%22&format=json](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22sfo%22&format=json)